# google cartographer

Tags: slam

can we use google cartographer without installing ros, like only using c++ or python?

I have tried looking for c++ but did not get how to use, but in some website it is shown we can see it without ros

Comment: `did not get how to use` ... what does that mean? ... what did you try? ... what difficulty did you have? ... please update your post ... do NOT add info into comments

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Google cartographer is released as a standalone library. See their homepage https://google-cartographer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> Cartographer is a standalone C++ library. To get started quickly, use our ROS integration.

The releases are on GitHub [here](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer).

The ROS bindings are the quickest way to get started. But you don't need them. If you're not familiar with how to download and use the package that they're making available. It may be easier for you to get started with the ROS packages.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR yes

All ROS packages are simply CMake packages or colcon packages that use the ROS messaging ecosystem. You can use Google Cartographer as a generic C++ library that is compiled from CMake files. You can tell it is a CMake project looking at their CMake files as well as their installation [scripts](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer/blob/master/scripts/install_cartographer_cmake.sh). This begs the question: why do you want to use cartographer without ROS? Do you already have a sensor and data processing pipeline suite set up? What is your desired application? Are you struggling with building ROS from source for your platform?  I suggest you learn CMake, Colcon, and ROS before making the judgement that you don't want ROS. I am making assumptions in this response, but it appears to me you don't have the context to know the benefits and drawbacks of including ROS in a project given the format of the question. I suggest you do some more research and understand how ROS is build and configured before deciding you don't want ROS.

Comment: thanks for the response, actually I am trying to build this in an embedded system, and for that ros might be heavy to compute that's why I am looking for something lite which will work for me